# Adding image WaterMark programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add an image watermark to another image. I have the following code but I'm facing a problem. I don't know what this 'Resources res' is.

Can anyone help?

```
public static Bitmap addWatermark(Resources res, Bitmap source)
{
     int w, h;
     Canvas c;
     Paint paint;
     Bitmap bmp, watermark;

     Matrix matrix;
     float scale;
     RectF r;

     w = source.getWidth();
     h = source.getHeight();


    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG |Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);         


    c = new Canvas(bmp);
    c.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);

    watermark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.android_mo);
    scale = (float) (((float) h * 0.10) / (float) watermark.getHeight());

    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    r = new RectF(0, 0, watermark.getWidth(), watermark.getHeight());
    matrix.mapRect(r);
    matrix.postTranslate(w - r.width(), h - r.height());

    c.drawBitmap(watermark, matrix, paint);
    watermark.recycle();

    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the Resource object you can have through `activity.getResources()` or `fragment.getResources()`

Answer (score 1):

```
Resources res
```

is the resource object that you need to pass from the calling Activity/Fragment.

suppose, if the method is in Utility class then invoke the method as

```
//Add watermark to the selected image
  Bitmap markedBitmap = Utility.addWatermark(context.getResources(), bitmap);
```

Comment: Sir In my case I want to share that image with watermark. How can i do that.

Comment: @NaveenKumarYadav addWatermark() method will give you a bitmap with the watermark added to the image. You can share this bitmap  to the server or can save it to local files

Answer (score 0):

Main bitmap is bmp1 and bmp2 transparante bitmap :

```
 public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
            Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
            return bmOverlay;
        }
```